# How do you write the projection operator of a direct sum in terms of basis elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum, projection, projection-matrices

Let $U$ and $V$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $U\cap V=\{0\}$, and let $P$ be the projection operator from $U+V$ to $U$. My question is, is there a way to explicitly compute $Px$ for any given $x\in U+V$?

Like if you fix bases for $U$ and $V$, is there a formula for $Px$ in terms of $x$, the basis elements of $U$, and the basis elements of $V$?

Comment: Because $U$ and $V$ have trivial intersection, their sum $U+V \cong U\oplus V$ is direct. Given $x$ in this sum, it is uniquely written as $x=x_U+x_V$ with $x_U\in U$ and $x_V\in V$. Then $Px$ is just $x_U$.

Comment: But the question is, how do you uniquely write it?  If I have a vector $x$, how do I get $x_U$?  Clearly there's only one choice of $x_U$ that will work, but how do I find it?

Comment: If you give yourself bases $B_U$ and $B_V$ of $U$ and $V$ respectively, their (disjoint) union $B=B_U\cup B_V$ is a basis for $U\oplus V$. Decompose $x$ inside this basis : $x=\sum_{e\in B_U}x_ee+\sum_{f\in B_V}x_ff$. Then $Px$ is exactly $\sum_{e\in B_U}x_ee$, the sum over the basis of $U$.